# Table and text appear too low down in the page when viewing in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, dreamweaver, cs4

I have one panel on the left side and have just added a table of images to the right beside it. In Mozilla the page looks fine, but in Explorer the table (and text above and below the table) start beneath the level of the left hand panel. Any suggestions on how to keep the main page contents at the right level?

The main bit of generated code was too long... here's the first half:

```
<div id="mainContent">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <h4 align="center"><strong>LITTLE MUNCHKINS BALTIC AMBER BEADS<br />
    INFANT AND TODDLER TEETHING NECKLACES</strong></h4>
  <h2 align="center"><strong> NZ SUMMER SALE ON ALL INFANT NECKLACES<br />
    were $35.00. Now just <u>$25.00</u>! </strong></h2>
  <p align="center"> <em>Limited time only!</em></p>
  <p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="justify"><strong>Our extensive range of Baltic amber necklaces includes rounded barock bead, olive shaped and chip beads in polished, semi-polished and unpolished amber.</strong> </p>
```

Comment: I just copied the main bit and it was too long... I'll copy and paste the first half..

Comment: <div id="mainContent">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h4 align="center"><strong>LITTLE MUNCHKINS BALTIC AMBER BEADS<br />
INFANT AND TODDLER TEETHING NECKLACES</strong></h4>
    <h2 align="center"><strong> NZ SUMMER SALE ON ALL INFANT NECKLACES<br />
      were $35.00. Now just <u>$25.00</u>! </strong></h2>
    <p align="center">  <em>Limited time only!</em></p>
    <p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="justify"><strong>Our extensive range of Baltic amber necklaces includes rounded barock bead, olive shaped and chip beads in polished, semi-polished and  unpolished amber.</strong>    </p>

Comment: Does that help at all?  The source code is all gibberish to me, sorry!